# PowerBuilder. Number Type for table Column in DataWindow

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder

I have got such code

```
table(column=(type=number updatewhereclause=no name=a dbname="a" )
column=(type=number updatewhereclause=no name=b dbname="b")
column=(type=number updatewhereclause=no name=c dbname="c" values="8    8/10    10/12   12/14   14/16   16/" ))
```

I read powerbuilder tutorial but don't find any information about "number" type.

Can anybody describe this type for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It appears as though the datawindow object in question is using an External Datasource.  Per the documentation:

> The number datatype is equivalent to the PowerBuilder double datatype.